# Can't install Python 3.8 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, python

As the title says I can't install Python 3.8 on Windows 10.

Some information:

- I had  the same Python version installed before, I uninstalled it (along with its launcher) using ccleaner (to install it in another path)
- I tried to install Python in a new folder but got an error because another installation was going on (it wasn't another Python installation, but another program)
- Now, when I try to install Python I get a message "No python 3.8 version was found" --> fatal error 0x80070643
- I used the software "everything" to remove python stuff from previous location
- I used ccleaner to clean registry
- I deleted pip folder from Appdata/Local
- I updated windows to the last version and rebooted
- I removed python from PATH

But the problem persists. What can I do now?

Log file: https://pastebin.com/wQizN9Nc

EDIT: I thought I had solved this because I could install Python, but now I get this error: https://imgur.com/Q2JtPg2

Both python and script folder are added to the Path, python --version on cmd returns correctly 3.8.0 but I can't open Python.exe (IDLE)

Comment: The only thing I see you have not attempted is a system restart.

Comment: In an elevated command prompt run the following two command, `msiexec /unreg` and `msiexec /regserver` then perform a reboot.

Comment: You may wish to try reinstalling to the exact same path (folder) as the previous installation. Then, rather than using CCleaner, simply use the normal Python uninstall link to remove it. In my experience, Python on Windows doesn't handle missing installations too well (since it assumes you may want to update the "current" installation if you have used the installer before). More generally, Python is one program I would avoid uninstalling with CCleaner in the future because of the behavior of the installer and the possibility CCleaner may not clean up the registry properly for it.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I've tried it and I got the same error

Comment: @Ramhound did that but still got the error :s

Comment: Please see [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) Solutions should be submitted as answers.

Comment: I would perhaps refer you back to my previous advice (uninstall Python with the official installer then reinstall it). However, before you do any reinstall, you may want to look at the Windows related answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38132755/3395469). Don't forget to install Python as an Admin either.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I did a repair installation and now everything seems to work fine, will add a detailed answer on how I solved it, still, I don't see any PYTHONPATH/PYTHONHOME in Windows Environment variables

Comment: PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME don't exist by default on Windows. They are (potentially) needed by some scripts/modules, however (though I believe Python itself actually ignores PYTHONHOME on Windows, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: Not a problem. You're welcome. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me.

AFTER all the operations in the OT, I've run Python 3.8 NORMAL installer and chose not to install py launcher, this made Python successfully install.

After this step, I have added Python and Python/Script folders to my PATH and in cmd, python --version showed the correct version installed.

THEN I got the last problem (the imgurl one), when trying to see pip version and install pip using python from command line. I fixed this last problem by opening again the Python installer and perform an installation repair. After this, I made sure I could use python and pip commands and that's it.

I didn't launch anything as administrator nor performed any reboot while doing these last operations.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for me was to uninstall Python3.x then re-install.

Make sure to check the box for "Add Python 3.x to Path" and then change the path installation path in "Customize Installation" in the installer.

I installed mine at C:/Python3. I also checked the box for "Install for all users" because that is what I wanted.